Upgrade to 24.04.1 LTS is failing ..upgrading from 24.04 LTS
The error message I get is

Could not download the upgrades The upgrade has aborted. Please check your Internet connection or installation media and try again. All files downloaded so far have been kept.
Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libm/libmodule-depends-perl/libmodule-depends-perl_0.16-5_all.deb
Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.81 80]

I also ran this manually and failed to receive the file causing the upgrade to fail.
... edit ...
when : today 30 August
ran ~# do-release-upgrade
Internet is working 100%
~$ curl http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libm/libmodule-depends-perl/libmodule-depends-perl_0.16-5_all.deb  << NO RESPONSE >>
using a browser to http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libm/libmodule-depends-perl/
the file is listed however clicking the link to download nothing is returned from the Web Server... tried 2 diff browsers...
LINK "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libm/libmodule-depends-perl/libmodule-depends-perl_0.16-5_all.deb"
I will also file a bug report. The ask > if others are experiencing same behavior?

More details please. What version were you running before? When did you run this command, today yesterday? What was the exact procedure you used ? What do you mean by ran it manually? This question needs a lot more info. Please edit the question and not answer in comments.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site, not for reporting bugs. What is the question?

Could not download the upgrades
The upgrade has aborted. Please check your Internet connection or
installation media and try again. All files downloaded so far have
been kept.
Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libm/libmodule-depends-perl/libmodule-depends-perl_0.16-5_all.deb
Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.81 80]

"Connection failed" is a network issue, not an Ubuntu fault. If your end of the network is working properly, then try again later.

@RDunn Anyways edit and update your question. The comments are mainly our way to ask you for clarification. Once you update the question, you may notify the person who asked for it by leaving a comment starting with @user as I have done at the beginning of this comment.

This question is similar to: Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04 Upgrade: Could not download the upgrades. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
